# Importing and synching polygons from a Google Spreadsheet into Carto - can it be done?

Tags: polygon, carto, spreadsheet

I have used Google Spreadsheets as a way to provide our large organisation a way to update carto maps with new locations without needing to consistently contact the web/GIS teams but only with pushpins.

I now have had a request to do this using polygons however I have no clue of if Carto will import (and synch) polygons from Google Spreadsheets and what format the geo-area field should be. The polygons do not change, just the values associated to the fields.

Any help or a sample spreadsheet would be wonderful.

e.g.
    District     | geojson | population |
    North East   | geojson | 2,340,000 |

Comment: can you give a more detailed example? is the geojson just with the geometry or also more associated values?

Comment: I have mocked up a simple spreadsheet with the nine weather districts of Victoria, Australia at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lOzBYFWD6YWs-wSdoOr5NpU-vvrFFfgZNftYStT7Yq4/edit?usp=sharing and I would like Carto to synch it every hour so that the layers appear like this mockup  https://dhhs.cartodb.com/viz/0f74f228-bc71-41bb-ab01-b5ebee3d75e2/embed_map but with the appropriate colours.  The issue is how to place the polygon into col c so it renders correctly and that users can use the hover popup to see the fire danger index.

Comment: your polygons don't change?

Comment: No they don't. If they do in a few years we would manually replace these with the new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments above it seems like your geometries don't change so what I think the best approach is to have a Google Spreadsheet with only the business data that changes. Then in your CARTO account, you have a *master table* with the geometries and consistent identifiers that you use to run a join analysis with  the synced table.

You have a full guide on the process [here](https://carto.com/learn/guides/analysis/add-columns-from-second-dataset/), which is called **Add columns from a second dataset**.

[image]

Comment: This looks excellent Jorge. Will have a play on Monday and see how it pans out. Most impressed and it keeps the kiddies away from the dangerous stuff in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Excellent, if you still have issues, add more detail to your question

Comment: Superb and it does exactly what it says. I have found three ways of doing this now with the one Jorge providing the best. The other two were SQL e,g,

 `SELECT 
serviceareas.cartodb_id,
serviceareas.the_geom,
serviceareas.servicearea, serviceareas.the_geom_webmercator,
safetyhubs.phonenumber 
FROM serviceareas 
INNER JOIN safetyhubs ON serviceareas.serviceareaid = safetyhubs.serviceareaid`

I was also told that you can use Well known Binary (WKB) as `the_geom`  field to get around this. This only works if each area is < 50,000 chars and sadly mine did not. Kudos Jorge!

Comment: awesome, thanks for adding a few more details for future visitors!!